# Hide & Show form for guest user's checkout on chekout page of woocommerce

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I am trying to add custom some links in checkout page for new user & guest user. By which user can select the option and will Hide/Show Or open to the appropriate form.

**There will two option based on custom links.**

> 1.If user want to create new account than user will select 'click here to registration' link & redirect to my account page.

> 2.If User select guest checkout option than guest checkout form will Hide/Show with toggle effect like "Have a coupon? ".

**What i have tried**

I use the following hooks to add links in checkout page

```
remove_action( 'woocommerce_before_checkout_form', 'woocommerce_checkout_coupon_form', 10 );

add_action( 'woocommerce_before_checkout_form', 'tr_checkout_before_customer_details', 10 );
add_action( 'woocommerce_before_checkout_form', 'woocommerce_checkout_coupon_form',12);

function tr_checkout_before_customer_details(){
    echo '<div class="woocommerce-info">
        Register as a user, <a href="/my-account/">Click here to register.</a>  </div>';

echo '<div class="woocommerce-info">
    Check out as guest .<a href="#" id="tar-tog-checkout-form">Click Here.</a> </div>';
}
```

Image attached

[image]

**Update 2**

For achieving the toggle behavior of guest checkout form i did the following.

1.I copy the form-checkout.php file to my child theme folder
2.I added the ID in form element

```
<form name="checkout" method="post" class="checkout woocommerce-checkout" action="<?php echo esc_url( wc_get_checkout_url() ); ?>" enctype="multipart/form-data" id="custom-checkout-form-id">
```

3.Added custom javascript file using wp_enqueue_script() function.My js file having following code

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {

    jQuery('#custom-checkout-form-id').hide(); //Initially form wil be hidden.
    jQuery('#tar-tog-checkout-form').click(function() {
    jQuery('#custom-checkout-form-id').toggle();
 });

});
```

Redirect to my account page is working fine . But i am unable to load form for guest user checkout like ***Have a coupon?*** effect.I am finding the solution for open the guest user checkout form with toggle effect like ***Have a coupon?***.

Any advice.

Comment: Which form? Can you elaborate on what you're trying to do?

Comment: Hi @Mokhless Thanks for reply.I have added some more details to the question to explain my issue.Please have a look.